# check if occurance of the same character in a string

Tags: c++

How I can check if each line of the text block below has the word 3 As together then save which line have it

```
12345ArAcAd21
32A293AaAbAc3
AaAcAd8922113
Aa34442108131
```

I extract each line into string array, the size of each row is 13, there are 4 rows. In the text block above we can see row 1, 2, 3 has 3Ax in a row, where x is a random character.
So I want to get the number 1, 2, 3.

How do I do that?

For now here what I have made

```
bool occur = true;
            for (size_t i = line.find("A"); i != string::npos; i = line.find("A", i + 2)) {
                if (line[i + 2] == 'A') {
                    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
                        if (line[i + x + 2] != 'A') {
                            occur = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // skips it
                    continue;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Absolutely no effort made in a solution. This is pretty basic C++.

Comment: Put the strings in a vector, and loop over the vector and use [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) to find the sub-strings?

Comment: @CoffeeandCode sorry about that, i have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you have declared occur as a bool and then you declared it again as an int. Probably this is why it is not working.

You can solve this problem very easily using regular expressions. Google "c++ regular expression" for more details. You can also ask me if there is any confusion. I am giving a sample code based on your input below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str[4];
    str[0] = "12345A5AcAd21";
    str[1] = "32A293AaAbAc3";
    str[2] = "AaAcAd8922113";
    str[3] = "Aa34442108131";

    for( int i=0; i<4; i++ ) { //for each string
        string line = str[i];

        regex e1(".*A.A.A.*"); //pattern = AxAxAx in any part of the string
        bool match = regex_match(line, e1);
        if(match) {
            cout << i << ": " << line << endl;
            //enter your code here
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
0: 12345ArAcAd21
1: 32A293AaAbAc3
2: AaAcAd8922113
```

Comment: thanks, what if AbAdAc? Ax, where x is random alphabet.

Comment: In AbAdAc, 3A's are not together. So the condition would not be true. But I thought that you only wanted 3A's to be together. :-o

Comment: yea, what if its like this, do I need to find each occurance of A and check if the next 3 A (index + 2) since there are 2 characters now. example AbAdAc, A is index 0, + 2 index 3 its still A, so on. is my logic right?

Comment: i have updated my question and a code, the code seems not to be correct though, its not getting the correct results.

Comment: sorry, I did not understand what you just said. Can you please say it more clearly? For example, do you want to know how many A there is in the string? Or do you just want to check if there is only 3 A's in the string?

Comment: thanks for helping , edited, that was a typo. can you provide me with an example? My occur bool is used to check whether the triple Ax combination has occured on the line or not.

Comment: I have included a sample solution in my answer. Check it out.